# FailedScheduling <unknown> default-scheduler 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) were unschedulable

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, plex

I'm recently getting started on kubernetes. I have encoutered `FailedScheduling <unknown> default-scheduler 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) were unschedulable` and am not sure what is happening.

Is it because there are not enough resources for a new pod on my node and i need to increase it? It doesn't look like it's using 100% of the memory or cpu yet though.

Here is my pod `kubectl describe pods plex-kube-plex-986cc6d98-lwns7 --namespace plex`

```
Name:           plex-kube-plex-986cc6d98-lwns7
Namespace:      plex
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=kube-plex
                pod-template-hash=986cc6d98
                release=plex
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/plex-kube-plex-986cc6d98
Init Containers:
  kube-plex-install:
    Image:      quay.io/munnerz/kube-plex:latest
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      cp
      /kube-plex
      /shared/kube-plex
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /shared from shared (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from plex-kube-plex-token-txkbn (ro)
Containers:
  plex:
    Image:       plexinc/pms-docker:1.16.0.1226-7eb2c8f6f
    Ports:       32400/TCP, 32400/TCP, 32443/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Liveness:    http-get http://:32400/identity delay=10s timeout=10s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:   http-get http://:32400/identity delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      TZ:                    Europe/London
      PLEX_CLAIM:            [claim-PooPBMsbyEjyigT-_hec]
      PMS_INTERNAL_ADDRESS:  http://plex-kube-plex:32400
      PMS_IMAGE:             plexinc/pms-docker:1.16.0.1226-7eb2c8f6f
      KUBE_NAMESPACE:        plex (v1:metadata.namespace)
      TRANSCODE_PVC:         plex-kube-plex-transcode
      DATA_PVC:              plex-kube-plex-data
      CONFIG_PVC:            plex-kube-plex-config
    Mounts:
      /config from config (rw)
      /data from data (rw)
      /shared from shared (rw)
      /transcode from transcode (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from plex-kube-plex-token-txkbn (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  plex-kube-plex-data
    ReadOnly:   false
  config:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  plex-kube-plex-config
    ReadOnly:   false
  transcode:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  shared:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  plex-kube-plex-token-txkbn:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  plex-kube-plex-token-txkbn
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
  ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) were unschedulable.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) were unschedulable.
```

Here is my node through minikube `kubectl describe node minikube --namespace plex`

```
Name:               minikube
Roles:              master
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=minikube
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    minikube.k8s.io/commit=93af9c1e43cab9618e301bc9fa720c63d5efa393
                    minikube.k8s.io/name=minikube
                    minikube.k8s.io/updated_at=2020_05_03T16_34_44_0700
                    minikube.k8s.io/version=v1.9.2
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Sun, 03 May 2020 16:34:38 +1000
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      true
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  minikube
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Thu, 18 Jun 2020 18:02:37 +1000
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Thu, 18 Jun 2020 18:01:11 +1000   Sun, 03 May 2020 16:34:33 +1000   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Thu, 18 Jun 2020 18:01:11 +1000   Sun, 03 May 2020 16:34:33 +1000   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Thu, 18 Jun 2020 18:01:11 +1000   Sun, 03 May 2020 16:34:33 +1000   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Thu, 18 Jun 2020 18:01:11 +1000   Sun, 03 May 2020 16:34:58 +1000   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  172.17.0.2
  Hostname:    minikube
Capacity:
  cpu:                4
  ephemeral-storage:  120997584Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             8037176Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                4
  ephemeral-storage:  120997584Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             8037176Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 21e345365a7e45a8ad5560eb273be8e5
  System UUID:                4b9e17f2-ea81-436d-bff9-1db34db18512
  Boot ID:                    6d7e3f0c-ce11-4860-a479-2d6dbfd72779
  Kernel Version:             4.15.0-101-generic
  OS Image:                   Ubuntu 19.10
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://19.3.2
  Kubelet Version:            v1.18.0
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.18.0
PodCIDR:                      10.244.0.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.0.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (11 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                          CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                          ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 coredns-66bff467f8-4psrb                      100m (2%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (2%)     46d
  kube-system                 coredns-66bff467f8-jgpgh                      100m (2%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (2%)     46d
  kube-system                 etcd-minikube                                 0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         46d
  kube-system                 kindnet-jzf4m                                 100m (2%)     100m (2%)   50Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)      46d
  kube-system                 kube-apiserver-minikube                       250m (6%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         46d
  kube-system                 kube-controller-manager-minikube              200m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         46d
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-hffcf                              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         46d
  kube-system                 kube-scheduler-minikube                       100m (2%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         46d
  kube-system                 storage-provisioner                           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         46d
  kubernetes-dashboard        dashboard-metrics-scraper-84bfdf55ff-2jc84    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         43d
  kubernetes-dashboard        kubernetes-dashboard-bc446cc64-kfk8z          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         43d
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                850m (21%)  100m (2%)
  memory             190Mi (2%)  390Mi (4%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
Events:              <none>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because the node is marked as `Unschedulable:true` and it has got a taint `node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule`

You can remove that taint and try

```
kubectl taint node minikube node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule-
```

Comment: But should i have a taint? I was just deploying a helms chart for a kube project, Why would this taint be here in the first place?

Comment: how did you setup kubernetes ? Generally master nodes by default has that taint to prevent workload being scheduled on master node

Comment: It was on a default minikube installation, Should i add more nodes via minikube ?

Comment: If you have followed this the master node should not have a taint actually https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/

Comment: It keeps putting the taint back even though i have used the remove taint command, How can i check why its happening? I have also deployed an SQL database and minikube dashboard on Kubernetes without problems.

Comment: check cpu, memory capacity of the master node. If there is no capacity then also it becomes unschedulable

Answer (score 4):

Got the same issue and @Arghya Sadhu answer does help.

```sh
$ kubectl patch nodes minikube --patch '{"spec":{"unschedulable": false}}'
```

Was enough to update the annotation along.

Right after, I noticed `kubectl` has the `cordon` and `uncordon` to "Mark node as un/schedulable".